# Creating a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nlp

I have a dictionary in Python and it currently looks like this:

```
{'apple': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'], 'banana': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'],
'carrot': ['file3.txt'],.....................................}
```

I have the contents of each file stored in a list of lists that contains the words from that file and also a general list of the files used:

```
[['hello', 'apple', 'test', 'banana'], ['weird', 'apple', 'tester', 'banana', 'apple'],........]]

['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', .....]
```

I would now like to create a new nested dictionary that contains all the information from the previous one but **also** the position in which the term appears in each document (if it exists in that document).

For example:
I'd want `print(dictionary['apple'])` to return `[{'file1.txt': [1]}, {'file2.txt': [1,4]},...... ]` (it tells me the document it appears in **AND** its position in that document)

My existing code for creating the dictionary I already have is:

```
dict = {}
for i in range(len(textfile_list)): #list of textfiles used
    check = file_contents  #contents of file in form [['word1',..],['word2','wordn',...]]
    for item in words:#a list of every word from every file ['word1','wordn','word3',...]
  
        if item in check:
            if item not in dict:
                dict[item] = []
  
            if item in dict:
                dict[item].append(textfile_list[i])

dict = {k: list(set(v)) for k, v in dict.items()}
```

How would I do this??

Comment: Hi, can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: @j1-lee n as in n-th word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could organize your workflow like the following. Use this as a source of inspiration:

```
content = [['hello', 'apple', 'test', 'banana'], ['weird', 'apple', 'tester', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple']]
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
index = {k:v for k, v in zip(files, content)}
words = set([word for words in index.values() for word in words])
expected_dict = {}
for word in words:
    expected_dict[word]=[]
    for key, value in index.items():
        if word in value:
            expected_dict[word].append({key:[idx for idx in range(len(value)) if value[idx]==word]})
```

output:

```
{'test': [{'file1.txt': [2]}],
 'apple': [{'file1.txt': [1]}, {'file2.txt': [1, 5]}],
 'banana': [{'file1.txt': [3]}, {'file2.txt': [3, 4]}],
 'tester': [{'file2.txt': [2]}],
 'hello': [{'file1.txt': [0]}],
 'weird': [{'file2.txt': [0]}]}
```